# Why are private inner classes not visible for static imports?

Tags: java, visibility

I defined a private inner enum class and tried to static import one of the enum values like this:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private enum InnerEnum {
        ONE,
        TWO
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print(ONE);
    }
}
```

This is not possible because the static import statement shown below is not visible:

```
import static OuterClass.InnerEnum.ONE;
```

I had to widen the visibility from `private` to `package private` to make it work. I know the semantic of `private` very well but my point is why the same code, once written as fully qualified enum value like this:

```
System.out.print(InnerEnum.ONE);
```

is valid but written like this:

```
import static OuterClass.InnerEnum.ONE;

...

System.out.print(ONE);
```

is not. A Java import statement (static or not) introduces only an alias. But for private types we are not allowed to introduce an alias. This seams weird to me.

Does anyone know the language design decision behind this restriction?

Which risk or danger would occur from allowing the static import in my case?

I am hardly interested in technical motivated reasons.

Comment: Because they're, err, private? You may be 'hardly interested in technically motivated reasons', but you're not going not get any other kind.

Comment: This is not the point. If I change `System.out.print(ONE)` into `System.out.print(InnerEnum.ONE)` everything is fine. Hence I don't see the point why the same File / Class does not allow a static import even so the code does access the same item

Answer (score 1):

One reason why it is not possible to simply allow import statements to statically import inner symbols is the fact that you can have more than one top-level symbol in the same Java source file.

The meaning of the single-static-import declaration is given in [JLS §7.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3):

> A single-static-import declaration imports all accessible static members with a given simple name from a type. This makes these static members available under their simple name **in the class and interface declarations of the compilation unit in which the single-static-import declaration appears**.

(emphasis mine). Now consider the following code, which is in a single compilation unit, say, `OuterClass.java`:

```
package mypackage;

import static mypackage.OuterClass.InnerEnum.ONE;

class OuterClass {
  private enum InnerEnum { ONE }
}

class OtherClass {
  void run() { System.out.println(ONE); }
}
```

Now: the quote above says that the static import *makes the `ONE` symbol available in the entire compilation unit* - which includes `OtherClass` - but `InnerEnum` should not be available in `OtherClass`, because it is private to `OuterClass`.

Basically, if you shouldn't be allowed to write that statement as `System.out.println(OuterClass.InnerEnum.ONE);` because of visibility reasons, you shouldn't be able to circumvent that via another mechanism like static imports.

Hence, statically importing private symbols should be (and is) prevented by the language design. (In fact, this is not limited to static imports: you can't `import mypackage.OuterClass.InnerEnum` either, for exactly the same reason.)

Comment: As far as I understand any import statements (static or not) they represent just conceptional aliases for fully qualified names. Hence if I have access (due to visibility) to a type, why not by using the alias? This only is my question, because to me it does not make any difference, except for technical reasons. In my opinion technical concerns should not have any influence to a language design. What's wrong with my expectation?

Comment: @Harmlezz I think that the problem is that your model of "imports as aliases" is not accurate. Based on my (totally rewritten) answer above, I would say that an import is more like a guarantee that the simple name of the symbol is able to be used in the whole of the compilation unit.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, but I sill disagree. In my opinion the statements made for static imports are motivated by technical concerns which are to strict or rigid. I added my very own answer now to explain my point in more detail. Hope you give it a try and read it. Would like to hear about your opinion afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

After reading JLS chapter 6.6 which is about access control ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6 )
There is no direct section about this issue.

But I have the feeling that the writers just thought it is too obvious that you do not need import on private members.

Later, they transferred this behaviour to static imports as well.

That's it.

Comment: Yeah. Before the introduction of static imports private imports made no sence. But now they are of some relevance. I do not understand why they added extra checks for import statements at all since checking the visibility of a symbol where it gets used should be enough and does happen anyways. Otherwise I can't imagine how they validate visibility for fully qualified types and entities.

Comment: I did'nt want to defend how it specified. I agree on your points.

Comment: I agree on your points. The check directly on the import statement introduces the "trouble". The import is done outside the code block of the class statement so it is not part of the visibility scope and the import on private fields will never be possible. IMHO opinion the spec has a flaw here and they should remove the requirement to check acccessibility at import level.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this :

```
public class OuterClass {

    private enum InnerEnum {
        ONE,
        TWO
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(InnerEnum.ONE);
    }    
}
```

But since it is private, you cant get it from `OuterClass`

Comment: This I know but the point is the static import. The full qualification seams to me to be equal to the static import.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it is a miss-conception of the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3) how it specifies a static import. I will try to explain my opinions:

1. **Conceptional** a *Java* import or static import introduces a simple name as an alias for a fully qualified name. Imports do not add any power to the *Java Language* but may improve the readability of source code only. If you take away imports from *Java* you will loose nothing but readability. Hence regarding all the access and visibility rules enforced by the *Java Language* their should be no differences between source code using the simple name and source code using the fully qualified name. If your source code compiles without imports and you replace later on fully qualified names with simple names by adding imports, the code should (in my opinion must) compile as it did before.
2. If the *Java Compiler* would accept a file defining no imports at all, using fully qualified types instead everywhere, this would imply that all access rules were satisfied.
3. **If** the *Java compiler* would compile a file in two phases like descriped below, a static import of an entity with private access scope would be possible:

   1. Replace all simple names with the fully qualified names
   2. Compile the file.

The flaw in the *Java Compiler* implementation is that it does apply access rules *ignoring* the scope of usage. It is too rigid by enforcing `public` and `package private` visibility while evaluating the import statements without inspecting the scope of use of the introduced simple names aka aliases.

A more sophisticated *Java Compiler* implementation would be able to allow static imports of private entities which wouldn't introduce any flaws to the code or disadvantages. The way the *Java Compiler* works now enforces either less readable code (in some cases) or widening the visibility of a private entity to a package private.

Further the *JLS* which (in my opinion) should be as free from technical concerns as possible, has introduced a rule which is unmotivated regarding the language design. As mentioned above in *1.* there is no need to enforce or assume visibility not respecting the scope of use.

I guess before the introduction of `static imports` there were no valid scenarios for imports of private types. Hence it could be assumed while parsing all imports that either the type was public or in the same package as the type which defined the import. I do not know why the compiler does check the visibility at all for imports, because checking it while parsing the token where the type is used should be enough and should occur anyway due to the existence of source code having fully qualified types.

After the introduction of `static imports` the assumption became untrue but the compiler was still in place. Instead of correcting the compiler to address the newly introduced scenarios where private entities are valid as well we stick with the old behavior. Code which does compile by using only fully qualified types and entities, may not after statically importing private entities which are visible in the scope where they get used. This behavior in my opinion is inconsistent and may make source code or class design worse.